# How to set extra profile fields for users like gender and age using Firebase Auth with Facebook and Google?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

How do I get the gender and age rage from Facebook and Google after Firebase Authentication in Android? `FirebaseUser` does not have the fields other than photo, display name, email, providerid and tokenid.

I have added both Facebook and Google birthday scope in `string.xml` as defined in the readme at [Firebase GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md), but couldn't figure out the extra fields retrieval. I am not that experienced with Android so I guess I am doing something wrong.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For facebook use method which Jitty posted. But for google use this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406660/how-to-get-gender-and-birthday-from-google-provider-using-firebaseauth/42456960#42456960

Answer (score 1):

***For Facebook :***

To get facebook accessToken from firebase is very simple. I was using firebase auth UI. After authentication with facebook you will get basic information from firebase user object like display name, email,provider details. But if you want more information like gender, birthday facebook Graph API is the solution. Once user authenticated with the facebook you can get access token like this.

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
```

But sometimes it will give you NULL value instead of valid access token. Make sure that you have initialized facebook SDK before that.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
  }
} After initialization use graphAPI

if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null) {

    System.out.println(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());

    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    // Application code
                    try {
                        String email = object.getString("email");
                        String gender = object.getString("gender");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Access Token NULL");
}
```

***For google :***

In your activity

```
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 8888;    

public void loadGoogleUserDetails() {
        try {
            // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic profile. ID and
            // basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();

            // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to GoogleSignIn.API and the options above.
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                            System.out.println("onConnectionFailed");
                        }
                    })
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .build();

            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




 @Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from
        //   GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                // Get account information
                String PhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();

            }
        }
    }
```