# How to get user's birthday after Google Sign-in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, deprecated, google-signin

As Google plus's person API is deprecated, I am unable to find any solution to retrieve user's birthday additional info.

I have tried `people:v1` library but Android Studio is showing the error message:

> Could not find method "com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev63-1.22.0"

My GMS Version = '11.0.2'
google-services => 3.1.0

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the user's birthday because it's a personal information. If you don't find any answer ask the user to give you his birthday and store it in SharedPreferences.

You can go watch [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406660/how-to-get-gender-and-birthday-from-google-provider-using-firebaseauth) if it can help you.

Hope you get what you need :)