# How to get birthday from google sign in using firebase? (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin

The only information I can get from google sign in is the displayname, email, number and etc. I would also like to get the birthdate but it isn't available. Can you help me? Thank you!

Here is my code for getting user information after logging in using google.

```
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
var googleIdToken;
FirebaseUser user;

Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {

   final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
   final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

 final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);

googleIdToken = googleSignInAuthentication.idToken;

final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
user = authResult.user;

AuthService().googleLogin(googleIdToken).then((val) {

  if (val.data['success']) {
     var token2 = val.data['token'];

     AuthService().getInfo(token2).then((val) async {         
       var store = val.data['user'];
      
       await UserSimplePreferences.setEmail(store['email']);
       await UserSimplePreferences.setFirstName(store['firstname']);
       await UserSimplePreferences.setLastName(store['lastname']);
       await UserSimplePreferences.setUsername(store['username']);

      showDialog(context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context){
            return  _SuucessLogin();
          });
      EasyLoading.dismiss();

     });
  } else {
    print('WRONG EMAIL/ PASS');
  }
});

assert(!user.isAnonymous);
assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
assert(currentUser.uid == user.uid);

return user;
}
```